# Meaning of 'after which'

Tags: word-usage

> Please sign the document and return after which our agent will contact you.

What does the sentence mean?

1. I should sign the document
2. I should return the document
3. After the second party receives the signed document they will contact me.
   Am I right ?

Comment: The sentence is missing the object of _return_, and it is possibly a fused sentence (two phrases were joined together without using the appropriate punctuation).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that's what it means. A comma after *return* would have been a kindness on their part.